# Arithmetic Operations in mongoDB using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, api, mongoose

I am trying to update content in the mongoDB database using node.js for a REST API. I tried using mongoose functions like $add,$inc, $dec. But it is giving me an error saying "Unknown modifier[image]"

Following is the part of the code where the function is being called : 
[image]
I am getting the correct outputs out of the console,log statements.

Where is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$add is a aggregation operater not a normal operater

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/

SO use $inc instead of $add, it will work with negative and positive values both.

```
admin.update({"username": donar}, {$inc: {"amount": -amount}}, 
function (err, doc){
if (err) throw err;

 else (res.json(doc));
})

customer.update({"username": recepient}, {$inc: {"amount":amount}},
function (err, doc){
if (err) throw err;

else (res.json(doc));
})
```

Comment: Thanks Puneet,
But I tried that as well, and got similar errors.
Also please tell me one thing, How can I convert the json object amount to integer?
I am getting that error as well

Comment: @NimitBedi I have checked the above code in my mongodb and it is working perfectly fine.
which npm module you are using to run mongodb queries in node.js?

I used mongoose on client side

Comment: I am also using mongoose. I'll check again once. thanks,
Any idea for the other issue?

Comment: Sorry i couldn't get your second query properly. Please update your question and mention your code, where you are getting problem. Then i can help you.

Comment: I'll check with that later. I am still getting that same error for $dec. have you installed any specific npm module?
or just working with mongoose?

Comment: use $inc in both increment and decrements, $dec is not an mongodb operator. And once it works for you please mark answer correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124696/discussion-between-puneet-singh-and-nimit-bedi).